# Infinispan JGROUPS force Change View

Tags: java, cluster-computing, infinispan, jgroups, wildfly-9

I'm working with Wildfly 9.x , with Infinispan 7.2.3. I'm facing up to the problem of forcing a jgroups change_view event in order to elect a different coordinator in a "predestroy" phase.

This snippet code :

```
Address localAddr=cacheManager.getAddress();
        Address coord=cacheManager.getMembers().get(0);
        if(!localAddr.equals(coord)) {
           logger.error("View can only be changed on coordinator");
            return;
        }
        if(cacheManager.getTransport().getMembers().size() == 1) {
             logger.error("Coordinator cannot change as view only has a single member");
            return;
        }

        long newId= cacheManager.getTransport().getViewId() + 1;
        List<Address> mbrs = cacheManager.getMembers();
        Address tmpCoord=mbrs.remove(0);
```

gives me this error:

```
10:13:28,688 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 95) WFLYEE0006: Failed to destroy component instance org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstance@5d8d8b5c: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentInstance.destroy(BasicComponentInstance.java:125)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.destroySingletonInstance(SingletonComponent.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.done(SingletonComponent.java:142)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponent.stop(EJBComponent.java:559)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$2.run(ComponentStartService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.remove(Collections.java:1317)
    at com.klopotek.core.session.job.SessionsHooverScheduler.changeView(SessionsHooverScheduler.java:219)
    at com.klopotek.core.session.job.SessionsHooverScheduler.stopJobs(SessionsHooverScheduler.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 24 more
```

Is there a way to force the set of a new view using infinispan?

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to get access to the JGroups channel, then [1] might work. IIRC the channel can be retrieved via `cache.getAdvancedCache().getRpcManager().getChannel()`, or some similar call...

[1] https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/wiki/Changing-the-coordinator-of-a-cluster

Comment: yes i already tried your example but through infinispan i was not able to reproduce it. i cannot find any getChannel() in RpcManager class... can you indicate precisely the right method?

Comment: i found this...http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_hijack_a_jgroups_channel_inside_infinispan_jboss_and_get_away_with_it

Comment: It is RpcManager.getTransport(), cast this to a JGroupsTransport, then call getChannel()

Comment: can you have a look at this link please? i have created a new thread related to a different problem with jgroups but strictly related to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700634/jgroups-transport-remoting-start-error-using-infinispan

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but change the coordinator for Infinispan might cause another change and maybe another rebalancing if you do so.
Also this behaviour might change with the next version.

Why you want to do it? If you shutdonw the node the coordinator is changed according to the policy and the caches are rebalanced (for distributed) to match the number of owners for a key.