# JGROUPS Transport remoting start error using Infinispan

Tags: java, infinispan, jgroups, wildfly-9, transport

In my use case I developed N webapplications, each of which uses Infinispan shared cache and JGroups as transport layer.

When a webapplication starts up, it creates a cachemanager object and registers it into the JNDI of the application server. The next started webcapplication  check the JNDI and if it finds a cachemanager already binded by another webapplication it uses it with a simple lookup calls.

This way the first webapplication instantiating the distributed cache manager should be the first actor which makes the jgroups channel to start, i.e. the coordinator.

The issue happens when:

1. I need to update all the webapplications by a hot deploy using new wars.
2. I undeploy all the war already running on the application server.
3. I deploy the new wars
4. All the wars are successfully deployed
5. 1 millsecond after the deploy, the load-balancer forwards all incoming client requests to the new available  webapplication services
6. the new invoked webapplication doesn't find any cache manager binded inside the JNDI so it creates a new one. This way it creates the new channel.
7. At this point i get this exception:

   ```
   15:36:41,742 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole) org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
   15:36:41,742 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:248) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   15:36:41,742 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:588) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
    15:36:41,743 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:554) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
    15:36:41,743 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:424) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
    15:36:41,743 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:397) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   15:36:41,743 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at com.society.core.session.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:162) [core-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
   15:36:41,744 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at com.society.core.session.SessionManager.<init>(SessionManager.java:184) [core-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
   15:36:41,744 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at com.society.core.auth.filter.KasPrincipalFilter.validateSession(KasPrincipalFilter.java:101) [core-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
   15:36:41,744 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at com.society.core.auth.filter.KasPrincipalFilter.doFilter(KasPrincipalFilter.java:54) [core-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
   15:36:41,745 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,745 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,745 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.6.jar:2.6]
   15:36:41,745 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,745 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,746 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (default task-7) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ISPN
   15:36:41,747 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,748 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,748 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=FRAG2
   15:36:41,751 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,752 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) [wildfly-undertow-9.0.1.Final.jar!/:9.0.1.Final]
   15:36:41,753 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=MFC
   15:36:41,764 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,766 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.UndertowAuthenticatedActionsHandler.handleRequest(UndertowAuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:66) [keycloak-undertow-adapter-1.7.0.Final.jar!/:1.7.0.Final]
   15:36:41,766 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,768 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,768 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,768 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=UFC
   15:36:41,777 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,778 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,780 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=GMS
   15:36:41,781 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,781 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,785 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)[undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,785 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,786 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,788 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (default task-8) ISPN000079: Channel ISPN local address is ws-7-aor-1951, physical addresses are [10.17.36.176:55992]
   15:36:41,786 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=STABLE
   15:36:41,794 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,798 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,799 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,801 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) [wildfly-undertow-9.0.1.Final.jar!/:9.0.1.Final]
   15:36:41,802 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,803 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69) [keycloak-undertow-adapter-1.7.0.Final.jar!/:1.7.0.Final]
   15:36:41,805 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=UNICAST3
   15:36:41,813 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,815 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,821 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]

   15:36:41,824 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)[undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,826 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172) [undertow-servlet-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,828 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]
   15:36:41,829 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774) [undertow-core-1.2.9.Final.jar!/:1.2.9.Final]

   15:36:41,829 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_51]
   15:36:41,829 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_51]
   15:36:41,830 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_51]
   15:36:41,830 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole) Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
   15:36:41,838 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:171) ~[infinispan-commons-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   15:36:41,839 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:869) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   15:36:41,840 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:638) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   15:36:41,841 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:627) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   15:36:41,840 WARNING [org.jgroups.jmx.JmxConfigurator] (default task-7) unregistering already registered MBean: org.infinispan2:type=protocol,cluster="ISPN",protocol=NAKACK2
   15:36:41,842 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-asyncConsole)        at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:530) ~[infinispan-core-7.2.3.Final.jar!/:7.2.3.Final]
   ```

Comment: Could you please manually undeploy all applications and check if everything was successfully unregistered from both JNDI and JMX? Perhaps the applications do not clean their resources properly.

Comment: the problem disappear when i add this property to the cache manager creation ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();builder.clustering().stateTransfer().awaitInitialTransfer(false); Why?????

Comment: Please see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619271/infinispan-jgroups-crashes-after-war-deploying/38741204#38741204) I gave to a similar post on having issues with sharing CacheManager instances via JNDI.

Comment: To the answer provided in the post, I'd add that really, each deployment should have its own cache manager and inject it via CDI to your app. If you want really share data, it's easier to use a remote cache server and then have use clients (along with near caching tech) to access that shared data.